# Arduino + node.js + socket.io - Object {valor: ArrayBuffer}

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, arduino

I send 1 by serialport on arduino to web by node and socket.io. The problem is that when I send the data I have:

```
Data: [object Object]
Data: [object Object]
...
```

but I want something like that

```
Data: 1
Data: 1
...
```

There is no value "1", I try to send string and still the same. Why is that?
Program works ok but this value problem is wall for me to go further I have a message in console:

```
userk@user-k52j:~/sio$ node app.js
http.listen
Port OPEN.
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead app.js:10:9
Socket.io connected.
```

But when I change sendfile to sendFile the program crash.

This is my programs:

Arduino:

```
void setup(){Serial.begin(9600);}
void loop(){
 Serial.println(1);
 delay(2000); 
}
```

app.js

```
var app = require("express")();
var express = require("express");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendfile("index.html");
});

var mySocket;

// Obsługa portu szeregowego
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;
var mySerial = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
        baudrate: 9600,
    });

mySerial.on("open", function(){
    console.log("Port OPEN.");
});
mySerial.on("data", function(data){
    //console.log("Data: " + data + 'ls/n');
    io.emit("dataArduino",{
        valor: data
    });
});
mySerial.on("error", function(error){
    console.log("Failed to open: " + error);
});

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("Socket.io polaczony.")
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("http.listen");
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Arduino node.js test</title>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var socket = io();
        socket.on("dataArduino", function(data){
            console.log(data);
            document.write("Data: "+ data + "<br />"); 
        });
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reading the documentation, I found  that `mySerial.on("data",` should be set after the open

Comment: It dont change anything, but thanks for trying :)

Comment: Perhaps simplify juste check the arduino<->nodejs without the nodejs<->browser, If you log on console `data`  int eh function `mySerial.on("data", function(data){` do you get what you want ?

Comment: I think problem is here:
`mySerial.on("open", function(){
    console.log("Port OPEN.");
    mySerial.on("data", function(data){
        console.log("Data: " + data);
        io.emit("dataArduino",{
            valor: data
        });
    });
});`
Becouse i do `document.write("Data: "+ JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "<br />");` and the string is: _Data: { "valor": {} }_ no value. But value in terminal is 1.

Comment: on `io.connect` you should connect to `serial`  on `serial open` you define `serial data` and on `serial data` you send on `io` Add log on each step, to see the progression and what is send. on browser log the received data and display it, you will then find where is the problem. I cannot understand your previous comment.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Without node.js is ok. I get my "1". Here is screenshot with webpage and console [link](http://imgur.com/TPdBsdK) when I string the data. Without string line is `Data: [object Object]`. Im preety sure that is something stupid and i think about it all day.